# Is there any replacement for ROWNUM in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jpa-2.1

I have JPA Native queries to an Oracle database. The only way I know to limit results is using 'rownum' in Oracle, but for some reason, query parser of a jar driver I have to use does not recognize it.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An exception occurred when executing the following query: "/* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT * from SFDC_ACCOUNT A  where  SBSC_TYP  = ?   and  rownum <= ?".  Cause: Invalid column name 'rownum'.  On line 1, column 90.  [parser-2900650]
com.compositesw.cdms.services.parser.ParserException: Invalid column name 'rownum'.  On line 1, column 90.  [parser-2900650]
```

How can I get rid of that?

Comment: It's suspicious that the error has the name in lower case. Does it make any difference if you use upper case `ROWNUM`? (I know it doesn't matter to Oracle, but that error isn't coming from the Oracle parser.) You could also try `row_number()` in a subquery.

Comment: Version of Oracle? 12c and higher supports fetch first X rows only syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Oracle's 'rownum' pseudocolumn with JPA Criteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911763/how-to-resolve-oracles-rownum-pseudocolumn-with-jpa-criteria-api)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and post the full exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

ANSI Standard would be something like the following

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
T.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.COLUMN ORDER BY T.COLUMN) ROWNUM_REPLACE
FROM TABLE T
)
WHERE
1=1
AND ROWNUM_REPLACE < 100
```

or you could also use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T
ORDER BY T.COLUMN
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```